# Source and Destination firestore size not matching after migration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate the Firestore data between the 2 projects. Followed this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data) to perform the migration. It seems like the migration has been completed successfully, however there is huge difference in **Storage(current)** between source and destination Firestore.

For example:
Source Storage = 20 GB
Destination Storage = 5 GB

Could you please help me in understanding the problem here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the same indexes in the destination? If not, that could explain as [indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#index-entry-size) typically contribute significantly to the total storage size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frank. Yes, I did define the single field and composite indexes correctly. And destination is matching with the source in terms of indexes.

Comment: Just noticed that there are `artifacts` which are in source project but not in destination project. Do we need to import these files? and what are these files?